# LINQ merge List<IEnumerable<T>> into one IEnumerable<T> by some rule

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have a `List<IEnumerable<double>>` containing variable number of infinite sources of double numbers. Lets say they are all wave generator functions and I need to superimpose them into a single wave generator represented by `IEnumerable<double>` simply by taking the next number out of each and suming them.

I know I can do this through iterator methods, something like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<double> Generator(List<IEnumerable<double>> wfuncs)
    {
        var funcs = from wfunc in wfuncs
                    select wfunc.GetEnumerator();

        while(true)
        {
            yield return funcs.Sum(s => s.Current);
            foreach (var i in funcs) i.MoveNext();
        }
    }
```

however, it seems rather "pedestrian". Is there a LINQ-ish way to achieve this?

Comment: `SelectMany`, maybe?

Comment: But how? I tried to wrap my head around it, with no luck. What I need is a weird variation of Zip() with variable number of sequences.

Comment: just wondering. why would you want it in LINQ? your implementation is  human readable and pretty nice.

Comment: And why you even would do that with LINQ? Have you seen the `Zip` source code http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,3ae08ae036c4ab24 Concentrate on your iterator function (currently it has bug)

Comment: I would write a method like this, just make sure it disposes of the enumerators, and I would also create the method such that it takes in the combinator delegate. The method in your question also reads `.Current` before caling `.MoveNext()` the first time, which is undefined. If you want I can post an answer with the way I would write your method.

Comment: Its ok, I just wrote this method out of my head as demonstration. I can always write it proper. I was just wondering if there is something out of the box so that I don't have to carry this method around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess there is no way around this without extending LINQ. So here's what I wrote in the end. I'll try to contact MoreLinq authors to get this included in some way, it can be useful in some pivoting scenarios:

```
public static class EvenMoreLinq
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Combines mulitiple sequences of elements into a single sequence, 
    /// by first pivoting all n-th elements across sequences 
    /// into a new sequence then applying resultSelector to collapse it
    /// into a single value and then collecting all those 
    /// results into a final sequence. 
    /// NOTE: The length of the resulting sequence is the length of the
    ///       shortest source sequence.
    /// Example (with sum result selector):
    ///  S1   S2   S2    |  ResultSeq
    ///   1    2    3    |          6 
    ///   5    6    7    |         18
    ///  10   20   30    |         60
    ///   6    -    7    |          -
    ///   -         -    |          
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">Source type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">Result type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">A sequence of sequences to be multi-ziped</param>
    /// <param name="resultSelector">function to compress a projected n-th column across sequences into a single result value</param>
    /// <returns>A sequence of results returned by resultSelector</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> MultiZip<TSource, TResult>
                                  this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> source, 
                                  Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (source.Any(s => s == null)) throw new ArgumentNullException("source", "One or more source elements are null");
        if (resultSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("resultSelector");

        var iterators = source.Select(s => s.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
        try
        {
            while (iterators.All(e => e.MoveNext()))
                yield return resultSelector(iterators.Select(e => e.Current));
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (var i in iterators) i.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

using this I managed to compress my combined generator:

```
interface IWaveGenerator
{
    IEnumerable<double> Generator(double timeSlice, double normalizationFactor = 1.0d);
}


[Export(typeof(IWaveGenerator))]
class CombinedWaveGenerator : IWaveGenerator
{
    private List<IWaveGenerator> constituentWaves;

    public IEnumerable<double> Generator(double timeSlice, double normalizationFactor = 1)
    {
        return constituentWaves.Select(wg => wg.Generator(timeSlice))
                               .MultiZip(t => t.Sum() * normalizationFactor);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Be sure to capture the result of `iterators` in an in-memory list or array. Otherwise, the call to `MoveNext()` will be working on a different enumerator object than the call to `.Current`: You're re-evaluating the `.Select()` every time you iterate over them.

Comment: True, overlooked that. Thanks.

Comment: `iterators` can never be `null`, so there's no point in null checking it.

Comment: On the other hand, `iterator` *could* be null, so it might be worth null-checking that variable before calling Dispose().

Comment: It cannot, it would break sooner on MoveNext. BUt I could receive nulls in `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>>`. Lets see if I can wrap this up nicer

Comment: Ok, caught the null entry in list of sources, if not-null then it will have an enumerator, so it cannot be null, so `MoveNext`, `Current` and `Dispose` will work.

Comment: Tidy solution and nice example as well

Answer (score 8):

You could aggregate the Zip-method over the IEnumerables.

```
    public IEnumerable<double> Generator(List<IEnumerable<double>> wfuncs)
    {
        return wfuncs.Aggregate((func, next) => func.Zip(next, (d, dnext) => d + dnext));
    }
```

What this does is bascically applies the same Zip-method over and over again. With four IEnumerables this would expand to:

```
wfuncs[0].Zip(wfuncs[1], (d, dnext) => d + dnext)
         .Zip(wfuncs[2], (d, dnext) => d + dnext)
         .Zip(wfuncs[3], (d, dnext) => d + dnext);
```

Try it out: [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vnuh45)

Comment: seems pretty alienish to me.

Comment: +1 for the constructive idea. However `Zip` stops when **any** of the enumerables involved ends, while what OP wants is to keep yielding until **all** end.

Comment: @IvanStoev: OP says that the `IEnumerable<>`s are "infinite", which I take to mean none of them will ever stop producing values.

Comment: The size of the sequence is not a show stopper, it would work, so +1, however its even more complex than the iterator method. I guess an extension is oin order

Comment: @StriplingWarrior So shouldn't then the Generator also never stop producing values? Which apparently is not the case with `Zip` implementation. Anyway, kind of "academic" discussion :-)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior  With this note in the OP own posted answer "NOTE: The length of the resulting sequence is the length of the shortest source sequence.", you win, so please ignore the above comments. It wasn't clear though until now. As usual here. frich, you already have my upvote, good job!

Comment: @IvanStoev: The `Zip` implementation would also never stop producing values as long as the source data keeps coming.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Take a look at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,3ae08ae036c4ab24, the line `while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())` Note the **&&**. I suggest to stop the discussion here, you were right for the OP case, I'm right for the other case, so peace please.

Comment: @IvanStoev: I apologize if I came across as confrontational. To clarify: if any of the streams stop, then Zip will stop, as will my example and the OP's answer. However, if all of the streams are infinite, then the result will also produce infinite values. Cheers.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Deal! Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

This is a situation where LINQ would probably be more difficult to understand, and not buy you anything. Your best bet is to just fix your sample method. Something like this should work:

```
public IEnumerable<double> Generator(IReadOnlyCollection<IEnumerable<double>> wfuncs)
{
    var enumerators = wfuncs.Select(wfunc => wfunc.GetEnumerator())
        .ToList();

    while(enumerators.All(e => e.MoveNext()))
    {
        yield return enumerators.Sum(s => s.Current);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is simple and easy to read. Sine you changed the type of the method input parameter, why didn't you just use `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>`? Do you fear the "outer" `IEnumerable<>` will be infinite as well?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Mostly, I just like using `IReadOnlyCollection<>`s. I find that they reduce the likelihood of the calling code having multiple-enumeration issues. But `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<>>` would be perfectly valid, especially if you're trying to make it more general-purpose, as mmix did in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple way to do this.

```
public IEnumerable<double> Generator(List<IEnumerable<double>> wfuncs)
{
    return wfuncs.SelectMany(list => list);
}
```